# "Shall" and "should" in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

I've been told that *will* becomes *would* in reported speech, e.g.:

> She said she **would** help me.

(I.e. in the past she said the phrase "I will help you")

What about *shall* and *should*, then? By the reasoning above *shall* should become *should* (no pun intended). Is this so? Also, what does *should* become in reported speech? Is it grammatically correct to say something like the following:

> Mark said Anna should not do this.

(I.e. in the past Mark said the phrase "Anna should not do this")

Should this "should" really become "shall"? If so, it seems to contradict the reasoning above... I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13370/modal-verbs-in-reported-speech?rq=1

Comment: @Jim, so my question is a downright duplicate, I'd say:) Should I delete the question or leave it as it is?

Comment: Does the other answer your question to your satisfaction?

Comment: @Jim it indeed does.

Comment: Ok then we can close this as a duplicate.